# Attach base64 string converted image to request form data in backend?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

so I have a base64 string that will be passed into an endpoint in which I need to convert it to an image then attach it in the form-data. Is that possible?

Right now I have something like this

```
Image img = options.base64String.ToImage();
```

And I want the image to be attached in the request's form data so I could get it like this:

```
Image img = options.base64String.ToImage();

Request.Form.Files.Add(img); // I want to add the image on something like this

var files = Request.Form.Files;
```

I want to attach the img to the `Request.Form.Files`

Also note that I only have access to the API of the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create a *new* request to some 3rd party API? It looks like you're trying to modify the current request object, which is something rather different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpRequest` object cannot be modified; it's immutable throughout the duration of the request. This includes the `HttpRequest.Form.Files`.

You can affect the way the request input stream data is processed. Since the input stream includes the Form fields, it might be possible to use filters to modify the form data on the request. However, it does have caveats:

- This only works *very* early on in the request pipeline. As soon as anything in the pipeline interacts with the input stream (including e.g. reading anything from `Form`), you're too late.
- You're working with the raw data stream. No `Form["Hello"]` is going to work here - you need to look at how HTTP forms are encoded, parse the data precisely, and recreate the correct changed form data on the fly.

Unless you really have no other option, I'd recommend avoiding that.

A relatively simple alternative would be creating a new web request using the actual request data, and returning the result from that (make sure the request you make doesn't cause another request, or you might end up with an infinite loop blocking your service :)). You'll need to make sure the new request you're making has all the right data, of course; there's no simple way to turn `HttpRequest` into a new `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. I have a solution for it, I also use images in my **ASP.NET Web App**.

I store images in **database** as `byte[]`, so a **byte array** and show images from this byte array, but update it with an `IFormFile` object.

For example I have an **User model** that stored in **database** who has `ProfilePic` property but also have another model (`ViewModel`) for update it.

My model to database:

```
class UserModel
{
    public byte[] ProfilePic{get;set;}
}
```

And my `ViewModel` to show or update profile picture of users is like this:

```
public class InputModel
{
    // actual image
    public byte[] ProfilePic { get; set; }

    // image to pass to POST method (so to update)
    public IFormFile ProfilePicToUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

When page is showing, I fill my profile pic array from database

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        ProfilePic = user.ProfilePic,
        XP = user.XP,
        Address = user.Address,
        BirthDate = user.BirthDate
    };
    return Page();
}
```

Show profile pic on page like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>Profile picture</h4>
    @if (Model.Input.ProfilePic != null)
    {
        <object class="" data="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Input.ProfilePic)" width="224" height="224" type="image/png"></object>
    }
    else
    {
        <img class="" src="~/images/profilePicDefault50x50.png" width="224" height="224" />
    }
    <input asp-for="Input.ProfilePicToUpdate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Input.ProfilePicToUpdate" class="text-danger"></span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

And process image in Post method like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile file = null)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    if(Input.ProfilePicToUpdate != null && Input.ProfilePicToUpdate.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await Input.ProfilePicToUpdate.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            var profilePicBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            if(user.ProfilePic == null || !profilePicBytes.SequenceEqual(user.ProfilePic))
            {
                user.ProfilePic = memoryStream.ToArray();
                var setProfilePic = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (!setProfilePic.Succeeded)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting profile picture for user with ID '{user.Id}'.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I don't think I quite get the example. Also just a note, I only have access on the API of the app so I can't really modify the front-end. I updated the question for more clarification.